# "Excel VBA Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" using JsonConverter

Tags: json, vba

Getting Error on "Excel VBA Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" using JsonConverter

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim products As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim data As String

strPath = "{'id':'p01','name':'Name1','Price':5.00}"
           
Set products = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strPath)

    i = 1

For Each Product In products
    'Cells(i, 1) = Product("id")
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Product("id")
    
    i = i + 1
   
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you get the `JsonConverter` library from? and which line is the error? is it `set products...` or is it `Sheet1.Cells(i,1) = Product("id")`

Answer (score 0):

`products` is a scripting dictionary, so you would be loop in over its keys:

```vb
Dim products As Object, k
Dim strPath As String
Dim data As String

strPath = "{'id':'p01','name':'Name1','Price':5.00}"
           
Set products = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strPath) '<< a Dictionary object

For Each k In products
    Debug.Print k, products(k)
Next
```

Comment: thanks i need more elaborate , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64158666/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch-using-jsonconverter