# Excel VBA Run-time error '13': Type mismatch using JsonConverter

Tags: json, excel, vba

Getting Error on "Excel VBA Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" using JsonConverter

my JSON

```
{"gstin":"33A","fp":"062020","b2b":[{"ctin":"33B","cfs":"Y","cfs3b":"Y","inv":[{"itms":[{"num":1801,"itm_det":{"csamt":0,"samt":83.97,"rt":18,"txval":933,"camt":83.97}}],"val":1050.94,"inv_typ":"R","pos":"33","idt":"10-06-2020","rchrg":"N","inum":"C3/071","chksum":"60a9044051e8b6ba1122f614143a4d1236b1399872b0ea408df6a82ba832253d"}],"fldtr1":"25-Jul-20","flprdr1":"Jun-20"}]}
```

my Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
.Title = "Select Json files"
.AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show() Then
        Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
        Dim content As String
        Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
        Open Filename For Input As #iFile
            content = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
            Dim products As Object, Item
            
            Set products = JsonConverter.ParseJson(content)
            i = 1
            
            
            For Each Item In products
                
                Debug.Print Item("gstin")
                'Cells(i, 1) = Item("ctin")
                'i = i + 1
            Next
        Close #iFile
    End If
 End With
 End Sub
```

also need to implement root and keys (like: gstin, ctin, csamt, inum)

Thanks

Comment: Its good etiquette to indicate the line causing the problem.  In the meantime, what type of data structure does JsonConverter.ParseJson return

Comment: gstin is String, fp is String and b2b is Collection, Debug.Print Item("gstin") line getting error type mismatch

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  What data type does JsonConverter.ParseJson return.

Comment: returned as "33A" as string

Answer (score 0):

Please limit to a single question. Your current error is because products is a dictionary and the keys are strings. You cannot do Item("gstin") as Item is a string. You would want initially products(Item) but won't be able to just use Debug.Print as not all the associated values in the dictionary are simple datatypes e.g. products("b2b") will return a collection and lead to a RTE 450 error due to incorrect syntax.

You will need to develop your code to test for which datatype is returned from the dictionary and any nested levels. [] indicates a collection you can For Each over, whereas {} indicates a dictionary. There are lots of examples on SO to help you with this and code examples that will write the entire structure out for you.

Comment: Hi, have a look first and see what you can find. I have outlined the problem and what you need to do. User omegastripes has written something really useful to this end.

Comment: hi, iam beginner for this, stuck in debug line, i have taken datatypes from json returned as gstin is String, fp is String and b2b is Collection, but don't know how to implement,

Comment: Debug.Print products("gstin") this is returned value from json but wrong loop (three times value returned)

Comment: you need to test each type e.g. Select Case typename(products(Item))  then if collection For Each etc.... Omegastripes has written a nice answer you can find for parsing json and writing out to a sheet.

Comment: not able to find @Omegastripes  answer, can you share the link

Comment: https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser See the examples listed. Also, answers like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50156323/6241235